# How to get data from database displaying in a list laravel

Tags: php, arrays, database, list, laravel

Whenever I am using this code I keep getting the following error:
"Trying to get property of non-object"

Controller:

```
public function createBooking()
{
    $products = DB::table('products')->orderBy('id', 'asc')->lists('id', 'name');
    return View::make('users.addbooking', array('products' => $products));
}
```

Blade View:

```
{{ Form::select('products', $products , Input::all('products')) }}
```

Comment: what is the output of `$products` ? have you tried to add `->get()` after `->lists('id', 'name')` ?

Comment: Did you add  `use DB;` ?

Comment: Are you completely sure you are getting error for those pieces of code?

Comment: I have a feeling it's because of the third parameter in the `Form::select` method. The third parameter should be your default value (if you want one), `Input::all('products')` as a default value doesn't seem right to me as you're throwing a whole array at the default value when it's not expecting that. Perhaps try setting that to `null` as it will be null on page load and if the page is reloaded it will automatically add in `Input::old('products')`. Check docs here: http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/html#drop-down-lists

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this out, I'm running laravel 5 and it works fine for me.

Controller:

```
public function createBooking()
{
    $products = DB::table('products')
        ->orderBy('id', 'asc')
        ->lists('name', 'id'); // checked some of my code I have these swapped value first then id
    return View::make('users.addbooking', array('products' => $products));
}
```

Blade:

```
{{ Form::select('products', ['' => 'Select'] + $products, '', ['class' => 'myClass', 'id' => 'myId'] }}
```

If you're getting the `Trying to get property of non-object` error, try this at after your query in your controller to check your getting the right results for your query:

```
dd($products);
```

Comment: I upgraded to Laravel 5 and this worked. Not sure what the error was. Thanks!

Comment: Glad you got it working in the end. Glad I could help you out.